# postgresql no downtime password rotation strategy

Tags: postgresql

Assuming we have a `ROLE` called `USER-A` with password `foo` and an app v1 using the latter.

Is there a better *no downtime* password rotation strategy in postgresql than:

1. `CREATE ROLE USER-B WITH PASSWORD "bar"`
2. Deploy app v2 using `USER-B`
3. Make sure no more app v1 are running.
4. `DROP ROLE "USER-A"`

I know it's a detail but I don't like the fact we are constantly changing the username.

Comment: Why are you constantly changing the *password*?

Comment: Because *security* and constantly is relative ;)

Comment: Why don't you change the password using `alter user`?

Comment: Because I don't want any downtime. reread the whole question maybe. thanks